# Removing disadvantage from being Small and wielding a Heavy weapon

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock

I rolled a Hexblade Warlock for a campaign I am playing, with the Pact of the Blade and Cursebringer invocation.

What I did not account for is that because I am playing a Halfling, I have disadvantage with my weapon (a silver greatsword).

Is any way to remove disadvantage  due to being Small and wielding a Heavy weapon without multiclassing? If its only possible with multiclassing, what is the smallest number of levels required?

I was thinking about a spell that increases my size like the enlarge reduce, but that is a second level spell for sorcerers and wizard only.

I am looking for specific items/spells that a warlock could use to counter this disadvantage that i could use consistently, so not a potion or something.

Comment: @V2Blast This question is smaller in scope, as it restricts it to consistent options for a warlock. Would that still be a dupe?

Comment: @Szega: I think it'd still be a duplicate of my question; even though the scope of this question is slightly more narrow, I don't think the difference is substantial enough for it to result in significantly different answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**By also having advantage**

Disadvantage is counteracted by also having advantage. Any method which will allow your Halfling to attack with advantage has the effect of removing your Disadvantage.

You will never have the ability to attack with Advantage, however, as a single instance of Disadvantage will nullify an infinite supply of conditions that give Advantage.

**Some examples include:**

- Faerie Fire, a great way to get advantage against targets
- Flanking the target, if your DM uses flanking rules
- Attacking a prone target. If you can land them on their back, your disadvantage is gone.
- Become invisible, or find some other way of attacking without being seen
- Stun or restrain the target.
- Having a familiar to use the Help action could work.

**However, there is a way to get SUPER advantage**

The Lucky Feat allows you to turn disadvantage into [super advantage](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/05/21/how-lucky-feat-works/) 3 times per long rest, allowing you to roll three times and picking one. This has the added possible benefit of being fairly fluffy for a Halfling, a race known for being lucky.

**Being a *bigger* Halfling**

Another option is to have somebody cast Enlarge/Reduce on you. It would increase your size, thus making you no longer small, and you would no longer have disadvantage. This has the added benefit of now being able to gain advantage, but it would require either a friendly wizard to cast the spell on you, or multiclassing into wizard yourself.