# How can a warlock use enlarge/reduce without multiclassing?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock

I was wondering if there is a way for a warlock to consistently use [*enlarge/reduce*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enlarge-reduce) (or any other second level spell that is not a warlock spell) without multiclassing. I was looking around but could only find ways to learn cantrips and first-level spells from other classes.

I am looking for a way to cast:

- A second-level spell
- from another class
- consistently (so not with a potion or spell scroll or other single-use solutions)
- without multiclassing
- following the rules as written

Comment: Trivially there are things like the Ring of Spell Storage (or something similar, I might have the name wrong) that allow *using* a spell without *learning* it. Would those be acceptable?

Comment: Does it have to be by officially existing classes/subclasses etc? E.g. could you work with a DM to come up with some homebrew invocations or pact features based on your specific patron?

Comment: Who else is in the party, and what are their classes?

Comment: By "consistently use enlarge/reduce", do you mean casting the Enlarge/Reduce spell on any target without any other limitations? Is it enough to be able to enlarge/reduce yourself only?

Comment: Given [your past question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/127799/removing-disadvantage-from-being-small-and-wielding-a-heavy-weapon) are you wanting to keep the halfling race as a requirement for answers to address?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Be a Duergar

There are no official ways to gain *enlarge/reduce* as a generic warlock as of 7-20-2018 without magic items, but [Duergar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/dwarf#GrayDwarfDuergar) (found in the *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*) gain it as a racial trait:

> **Duergar Magic**
>
> When you reach 3rd level, you can cast the *enlarge/reduce* spell on yourself once with this trait, using only the spell’s enlarge option.

You can only use it once before a long rest and only for the enlarge option on yourself. For only official ways, though, this is what you've got.

Comment: Yeah, maybe beyond scope.

Comment: If you're a duergar, you don't need to Enlarge to bypass disadvantage on the heavy weapon.

Comment: @NautArch this question doesn't ask about avoiding small size weapon penalties

Comment: You are correct, sir! I was drawing the line between [their original question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/127799/removing-disadvantage-from-being-small-and-wielding-a-heavy-weapon) and this one. But that's not necessarily relevant.

Comment: Pact Magic slots are per short rest and are thus more available than you're giving them credit for, assuming your party isn't embracing the Wizard's workday.

Comment: @BenBarden youre right. Brain fart

Answer (score 16):

## Acquire a *Staff of the Magi*

One of the many, many benefits of attuning a [*Staff of the Magi*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/staff-of-the-magi) is:

> You can also use an action to cast one of the following spells from the staff without using any charges: arcane lock, detect magic, enlarge/reduce, light, mage hand, or protection from evil and good.

This has no limitation and can be used as much as you like.  The staff is attuneable by warlocks, but you should be aware it is a Legendary magic item, and thus not something trivially acquired, even with dedication.

As an aside, there is one in *Tales From the Yawning Portal*'s *Tomb of Horrors* conversion.  Good luck getting it out in working order and with the party alive, though

Answer (score 5):

## There is no way for a Warlock to get access to above 1st level spells from another classes' spell list without multiclassing

Outside of the existing Eldritch Invocations (i.e. Whispers of the Grave allows you to cast *speak with dead* at will), there are otherwise no way to get a spell from another list.

To list some things that won't help you:

- Bards can with Magical Secrets, but Bards are not Warlocks, so this isn't going to work for you.
- There is the Magic Initiate feat, but it only gives you access to a 1st level spell and cantrips.
- Certain races can also cast spells innately (such as Duergar, which can cast *enlarge/reduce* innately).

However, both of these last two are "once per long rest" (as are many of the Eldritch Invocations, incidentally, such as Sculptor of Flesh, as an example) so does not meet your "consistently" requirement (since I would say "once per long rest" counts as being a "single use solution", as you put it).

So unfortunately I think either multiclassing or simply not having the spell are your only options.

Comment: How about the ritual spells for tome warlocks?

Answer (score -3):

## There is always a way!

Though what I have in mind is in no way efficient in my opinion.

An answer to another question [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/109346) is talking about paid services for spells cast by NPCs.

With that in mind, if you can get your hand on an [Ioun Stone (Reserve)](https://open5e.com/equipment/magic-items/ioun-stone.html), you can get an NPC to cast Enlarge/Reduce on the stone and keep it until you need it. Note that the stone can only hold one casting of the spell since it's a level 2 spell.

Comment: While this was my first thought based on the title, the text of the question mentions it needs to be "consistently" usable. Ioun Stones are not.

Comment: @DannyCuppen they are if you have a friend who can consistently cast enlarge into them.

Comment: @DannyCuppen It maybe a bigger period than once per long rest, but it's in no way a single use thing. It does cost some gold each use and it's once per city visit. Consistency exists.